# IDFA/GAID letter case

Tags: android, ios, mobile, ads, idfa

Is there a standard/convention regarding the letter case of IDFA (Identifier for Advertising) and GAID (Google Advertising ID)?

I couldn't find anything conclusive about this. Links to relevant documents will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

It seems from the examples in [Advertising ID Documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/id.html) that GAID is stored lowercase, the last example also shows a wrapper class which might mean you don't have to worry about this.

With regards to the Apple version I could not see any examples in their own documentation, but the example shown on [Possible Mobile](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/)'s article on Unique Identifiers shows it in Uppercase. I don't know the site to say whether thats actually a reliable source. Like Android, Apple has some [wrapper classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012654-CH1-SW5) which seem to provide the ID to you so you again might not need to worry about formatting.

Answer (score 3):

From what I've seen, IDFA is uppercase and GAID is lower case.  Sorry, no links.

Comment: This is a rubbish answer

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen IDFA is always in Upper case and GAID is in small case

Comment: Relevant links would make this answer great!

Answer (score 0):

They are not case sensitive and any company who treats them as such is doomed to have a terrible time. UUIDs are numbers, no more no less.

You cannot deduce the OS from the cased-ness of the IFA. Think about it... this would mean there can only ever be two mobile device operating systems ever.